# Multiple Trees from a set of related objects in C#

Tags: c#, linq

We are creating a blogging application and need to organise all the comments into a hierarchial tree.

Infact I think this is multi tree structure.

A simplified version of a comment class:

```
Class Comment
{
 public string CommentId {get; set;}
 public string  ParentCommentId {get; set;}
 public string  Comment{get; set;}
}
```

When someone makes a new comment (say a), the ParentCommentId will be null. Much like the root of a tree.

When someone replies to that comment (a), then a new comment will be created (say b) and it will inherit the the main comment's Id as its ParentCommentId.

Then again if someone replies to this new comment (b), a new comment will be created(say c) and it gets the second comments (b) Id as its ParentCommentId .

Basically a multiple tree structure with each tree root being the result of someone creating a new comment (a) (i.e. NOT replying to someon else's comment (b,c)

Could some genius tell us how we can efficiently grab all the comments into such a structure preferably using Linq.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you pulling these comments from a database?

Comment: @Jason Does it matter where they come from? They are just a stream of Comment objects. Could be from Database, could be from csv, could be from Lucene Index etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking something like this by using recursive linq query:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    const int maxDepth=3;

    class Comment
    {
        public string CommentId {get; set;}
        public string  ParentCommentId {get; set;}
        public string  CommentText{get; set;}
        public List<Comment> ChildComments { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

         List<Comment> comments = new List<Comment>()
        {


            new Comment () { CommentId = "1", CommentText = "Comment 1", ParentCommentId = ""},
            new Comment () { CommentId = "2", CommentText = "Comment 2", ParentCommentId = ""},


            new Comment () { CommentId = "3", CommentText = "Sub Comment 1 of 1", ParentCommentId = "1"},
            new Comment () { CommentId = "4", CommentText = "Sub Comment 1 of 2", ParentCommentId = "2"},

            new Comment () { CommentId = "5", CommentText = "Sub Comment 2 of 1", ParentCommentId = "3"},


            new Comment () { CommentId = "6", CommentText = "Sub Comment 1 of 5", ParentCommentId = "5"},
            new Comment () { CommentId = "7", CommentText = "Sub Comment 1 of 6", ParentCommentId = "6"},
             new Comment () { CommentId = "8", CommentText = "Sub Comment 1 of 7", ParentCommentId = "7"},  
        };


        var formattedList =  GetChildComments(comments, "", 1);

        Console.WriteLine(formattedList.Count()); //2
        Console.WriteLine(formattedList[0].ChildComments.Count()); //1
        Console.WriteLine(formattedList[1].ChildComments.Count());//1

        Console.WriteLine(formattedList[0].ChildComments[0].ChildComments.Count());//1


    }

    private static List<Comment> GetChildComments(List<Comment> comments, string parentCommentId, int depth)
    {
        if(depth>maxDepth)
        {
            return new List<Comment>();
        }

        return comments
                .Where(c => c.ParentCommentId == parentCommentId)
                .Select(c => new Comment { 
                   CommentId = c.CommentId, 
                              CommentText = c.CommentText, 
                              ParentCommentId = c.ParentCommentId, 
                              ChildComments = GetChildComments(comments, c.CommentId,  depth+1)})
                .ToList();
    }
}
```

You can see it working at [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1sX6s2)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there an easy way to limit each the root tree (i.e. the main comment which has blank as Parentid) to a specific number of child trees. Like 3,4,5 or whatever.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more? I am not clear on what you mean by "limit each the root..".

Comment: Hi. Each new comment that is created with a blank ParentId lets call this the Master. We can have several Masters when new Comments are created. Each of these masters when users reply to, start a chain of chil trees. I would like to limit how deep this tree structure can become based on a figure. So if this figure is 3 we can have the Master, the first child tree, then the first child tree of the first child. Thanks

Comment: Got you now, you can pass depth to "GetChildComments" to achieve this, I will update the code once I will get access to my laptop.

Comment: See the code updated with depth, you need to change the maxDepth constant value defined at the top, you can see working sample here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1sX6s2

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a genius.

Comment: I am glad my solution helped!